# Can django superuser first and last name be updated? If yes, how do I go about it?

Tags: django

I'm want to render superuser first and last name on my html page. But django tutorials don't show how to add these fields to the superuser. How can I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: A superuser is just a user with `is_staff` and `is_superuser` set on `True`. So you can edit it, like any other user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A superuser is just another user, with as difference that the `is_staff` and `is_superuser` fields are set to `True`. You thus can edit the user, for example in the admin site:

[image: Admin panel with superuser]

Or you can change the `first_name` and `last_name` of *all* super users with:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

get_user_model().objects.filter(is_superuser=True).update(
    first_name='Super', last_name='User'
)
```